# Auto refresh iframe not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code

```
 <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" name="isfsf">
 </iframe>

 <script>
 window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);

  function reloadIFrame() {
  document.frames["isfsf"].location.reload();
 }
 </script>
```

Auto refresh iframe not working? please help me

Comment: Change window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000); to window.setInterval(function(){reloadIFrame();}, 3000);

Answer (score 1):

Try this . for working below code don't forget to include jquery library.
its will refresh iframe tag in every 3 seconds

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

setInterval(function(){

        var url=$('iframe').attr('src');
        $('iframe').attr('src',url);

},3000);


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
window.setInterval(function(){ reloadIFrame() },3000);

function reloadIFrame() {
    document.getElementById('isfsf').contentWindow.location.reload();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function refresh()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
    iframe.reload(true);
}

setTimeout('refresh()', 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('isfsf').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

or

```
document.getElementById('isfsf').src = document.getElementById('isfsf').src;
```